# Prevent DOM elements from rendering on server side with angular universal

Tags: angular, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

Is it possible to prevent elements from being rendered on the server when using angular universal?  Specifically, I want to prevent ads from being rendered on the server as they are slowing down page load speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ngIf` and test `isPlatformBrowser` with injected `PLATFORM_ID`.